# PostGIS: Can´t preview geometry when in different schema than public - why?

Tags: postgis, pgadmin-4

So I'm trying to wrap my head around PostGIS and how to get it working correctly in a schema other than 'public'.

I followed [this](https://postgis.net/2017/11/07/tip-move-postgis-schema/) tutorial, and transfered PostGIS to my own schema, postgis_test. I used the PostGIS shapefile importer and imported my shapefile. Everything looks good (see screenshot of the geometry column), but the option to preview the geometry (the 'Eye'-icon) from the table is gone - why could that be?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

PostGIS should stay in the public schema (then everyone can see it) while your data can live in individual schemas. This allows you to upgrade PostGIS without needing to backup, drop and restore the data tables since only public needs to be changed.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that might be the case. But how then, do I use the shapefile importer to import files to schemas other than the PostGIS enabled public? When I tried that earlier it just failed, and the solution I found was to move postgis to the schema where I wanted my data (obviously not a good idea).

Comment: then you need to ask a new question - I've never seen that before but I use ogr2ogr or qgis to do my imports